# UI blocked with Async/Await

Tags: c#, .net, events, asynchronous, async-await

This question is somehow asked in many threads here, but I couldn't find a clear answer to my case, I have a simple code, a `Button`, a `Textbox` and a `ButtonClickEventHandler`, this latter despite being `Async`, keeps the UI blocking, code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task t = new Task(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke((()=>
                    {
                        TextBox.Text += i.ToString();
                    }));
                }
            });
            t.Start();
            await t;

            //Something else
        }

    }
```

Xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="180,10,185,277" x:Name="Button" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
           Ok
        </Button>
        <TextBox Margin="29,83,40,33" x:Name="TextBox"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

First, why is this happening ?
Second, what I should I do to make the UI keeps working normally without hanging, always by following this logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have noted, if you attempt to update your UI too frequently, you will end up blocking user interaction.

As far as your code goes, you should be using `Task.Run` instead of the task constructor, and `IProgress<T>` instead of `Dispatcher.Invoke`. I have an [`IProgress<T>` implementation that handles throttling for you](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/4248e50b4cb52b933c0d), which can be used as such:

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  using (var progress = ObservableProgress<int>.CreateForUi(value => UpdateUi(value)))
  {
    await Task.Run(() => BackgroundOperation(progress));
  }

  ...
}

private static void UpdateUi(int progressUpdate)
{
  TextBox.Text += progressUpdate.ToString();
}

private static void BackgroundOperation(IProgress<int> progress)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    if (progress != null)
      progress.Update(i);
  }
}
```

No artificial delays necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Define "blocked". The code you posted will *not* block the UI. But it will sure keep it really busy, which may well have the effect of it *seeming* like it's blocked. And for that matter, blocking it for all practical purposes even though it's not really.

You're basically executing a denial-of-service attack on your GUI thread. You've got a secondary thread in a tight loop that just keep executing stuff on the GUI thread. Don't do that and things will be much better.

Comment: By blocked I mean not-responsive, hung, can't click, can't move window or interact with UI ... please don't complicate things for me I wan't to do that operation, and I want to keep executing it while keeping the UI responsive

Comment: @AymenDaoudi He's right though... That code is gonna lock the CPU. Add a `Thread.Sleep(20)` (20 in this case means 20 milliseconds) into your `for` loop and it will start working fine.

Comment: @AymenDaoudi: sorry if you think I'm complicating things. All I'm doing is answering your question. The word "block" has various meanings, thus my initial statement. Technically your GUI thread is not blocked, but by your own definition of "non-responsive", it absolutely is, and it's precisely because of the reason I stated. As Ruslan notes, if you put any significant delay into that loop, things will work much better. Of course, one hopes that in reality your secondary thread has more interesting things to do and won't even need to be arbitrarily slowed down just to keep the GUI working. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I see, I just tried that and it works, but I don't understand why that doesn't work, why should I add that delay to keep the UI responsive ?

Comment: +1. @AymenDaoudi UI is responsive, you are just way to slow to compete with requests generated by CPU. When you slow down rate of requests from other thread (i.e. by `Sleep`) you have chance to respond to your (and also WM_PAINT) requests.